# Unable to connect using Stomp client from Mobile Native Android / iOS app Using ws or wss

Tags: android, sockets, mobile, stomp

Unable to connect using Stomp client from Mobile Native Android / iOS app Using ws or wss from Using ws or wss.

Gives following Error:

"Websocket: onClosed : Expected HTTP 101 response but was '200 'Response{protocol=http/1.1, code=200, message=, url=https://myURL/}"

Working fine when try to connect open network server.

But unable to connect ngnix configured server.
Where Socket connected successfully from Web/ Web view.

Answer (score 0):

It's not a real problem. The server tells you it try to elevate HTTP request in as WebSocket request.

My project is still a work in progress, but I think it could be useful as case study.

- [spring boot backend](https://github.com/xcesco/reversi-backend)
- [android client](https://github.com/xcesco/reversi-android)